# Calculating terrain attributes before or after upscaling DEM

Tags: gdal, dem, gdalwarp, slope

This is more of a theory question. I am working on a project that requires the use of topography data, I have a 1KM resolution global DEM to which I will be using GDAL to calculate general topography attributes such as aspect, slope TRI etc.

The problem is that we will be working at a 4KM resolution, thus we will be upscaling the resolution of our DEM. When calculating slope for example, I found myself with two options, calculate slope at 1KM resolution and then upscale both elevation and slope to 4KM **or** upscale the DEM to 4KM and then calculate slope. Needless to say, the results are numerically different for both approaches, although the general relationship is the same (as in, mountain areas seem to have higher steepness for example).

I do not have a strong geology background.

How should I proceed on this type of situation?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention "aspect", then I would definitely suggest that you derive your indices at 4km resolution. Aspect is indeed not "upscalable" because of its polar construction (from 0 to 360, where 0 is equivalent to 360, and -1 when it is completely flat).